# How can a remotely hosted project (on a linux server) be set up in Aptana Studio 3?

Tags: php, installation, aptana3

Warning! I am a complete PHP newb...I have been in the MS ecosphere for my whole career. Don't assume I know anything. Thanks!

Here's the topography:

1. Developing on windows 7 machine. Aptana Studio installed.
2. Linux server with PHP and frameworks installed.

Here's what I want to be able to do:

1. Create a PHP project in Aptana Studio
2. Develop from within Aptana studio
3. Test the application
4. Upload to the files to the server (or alternatively, they are hosted on the server and Aptana is just editing them.

How do I set this up? I don't want to install WAMP or anything on my dev machine. I just want to use the PHP libraries on the remote server to be used.

I'm assumming that if I create a PHP project in Aptana studio, it won't work unless I have WAMP installed or use a remote PHP-enabled linux server to test and run the app.

And lastely...if I want to use cakePHP, I assume with this setup I am asking for I can just install it on the remote server and then use the libraries?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

My personal setup is very similar to yours. I create a project, then add a connection. This connection uses SFTP to connect to the Linux server and it points to the folder with the PHP files. You can then open, edit and save all these files from within Aptana (as long as you are connected of course).

The only downside of this is that since Aptana does not perceive this SFTP connection as local, you can't use the more extensive code searches and the likes. If this is a no-go for you, you might take a look at mounting the SFTP folder as a drive on Windows. You can then trick Aptana into thinking it's a local folder, and then all the bells and whistles will work, be it a little slow :)